# Perform git tfs rcheckin but with different comment?

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have the following case: 2 Visual Studio Team Services, one internal for my company to manage workitems and another one that our customer has to manage its own work items, and we have an application that synchronizes the work items of both systems.

E.g. mapping the work item "Make a potato" with ID 123 in Client VSTS to "Make a potato" with ID 456 in our VSTS.

Our customer also has a TFS with some solutions, and we have used Git-Tfs to create a Git repository from that TFS. On our Git, we want to write our commit comments like this: "Implemented Potato (#456)" (with the ID of the Work Item that lies on our backlog). However, when performing rcheckin, we need to modify the comment to "Implemented Potato (#123)" so that rcheckin assigns the proper Work Item from the client. (We have a Mapping file which is basically a txt file with the shape 123 -> 456)

Is there any way or any idea about how to do this (if possible at all)?

Comment: Do your team work on the Git repository that cloned from TFS via git-tfs directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't find a way to modify the comments. Comments in TFS are preserved.